# Java - how to pass items from ArrayList in one class to constructor//getter and setter in another?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, model

Would like some advice on how to access items from an `ArrayList` and pass them to a constructor.

I have this code that generates and stores 2 `ArrayLists` of `Integer` and `Date`:

```
ArrayList <Date> days = new ArrayList<>();
Integer[] count = {0,0,0,0,0,0}; //Use Integer not int
List<Integer> recordCount = Arrays.asList(count);

for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
    days.add(dateUtils.stringToDateWithTime(lastWeek.toString()));                     
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}

for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < r.size(); y++) {
        if (!(days.get(x) == r.get(y).getDate())) {
            int oldValue = recordCount.get(x);
            int newValue = oldValue + 1;
            recordCount.set(x, newValue);
        }
    }
}
dataModel.setyValueCount(what do i put in here?);
dataModel.setxValueDate();
```

And where I would like to pass them to is my `DataModel` class:

```
public class DataModel {

    private long yValueCount;
    private Date xValueDate;

    private String someStringField;
    private String label;

    public DataModel() {

    }

    public DataModel(Date xValueDate, int yValueCount) {
        this.xValueDate = xValueDate;
        this.yValueCount = yValueCount;
    }

    public long getyValueCount() {
        return yValueCount;
    }

    public void setyValueCount(long yValueCount) {
        this.yValueCount = yValueCount;

    }

    public Date getxValueDate() {
        return xValueDate;
    }

    public void setxValueDate(Date xValueDate) {
        this.xValueDate = xValueDate;
    }

}
```

This data is to be inserted into a chart that will be displayed in the app. Thanks.

Comment: please elaborate your question `dataModel.setyValueCount(what do i put in here?);` what do you want to put?

Comment: I meant what am I meant to put in those parentheses to pass the data from the arraylist to the constructor in the next class, sorry if it was confusing!

Comment: there is no info to indicate what value should be passed here, even the `setyValueCount`, what is it for? what do you want it to be used as?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass the data from the arraylist to the constructor"? Firstly, `setyValueCount()` is not a constructor, secondly it erquires a `long` and not an `ArrayList`. So, is your question how to parse an `ArrayList` into a `long` value? (because that's not really gonna work...)

Comment: Please provide more information, on how you want to use the ArrayLists in your DataModel class.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x = 0;x<7;x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < r.size(); y++) {
           //create object here
           DataModel dataModel=new DataModel();
        if (!(days.get(x) == r.get(y).getDate())) {
            int oldValue = recordCount.get(x);
            int newValue = oldValue + 1;
            recordCount.set(x, newValue);
            //set here what do you want
            dataModel.setyValueCount(long type);
            dataModel.setxValueDate(Date type);
           //use  dataModel object for any other process like persist
          //looking for this or any other..........?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ... this is not even going to compile.